# How to retrieve Game center's achievement percentage and submit back with modification?

Tags: ios, game-center

I have already configured all Game Center functions and below code i am using to unlock achievement, which is perfectly working fine.

```
- (void) unlockAchievementThis:(NSString*)achievementID {
    GKAchievement *achievement = [[GKAchievement alloc] initWithIdentifier:
                                  achievementID];
    if (achievement){
        achievement.percentComplete = 100;
        achievement.showsCompletionBanner = true;
        [GKAchievement reportAchievements:@[achievement] withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
            if (error != nil) {
                NSLog(@"Error at unlockAchievementThis()");
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

Now My problem is with incremental achievements. I have another method for few achievements and I want the previous achievement percentage to increase it with a constant.

My game is in cpp and i don't know much ObjC.
I got some code below which i think should help me but i don't know how to use **achievementDescriptions** to get percentage and add **incStep** into it and submit it to back game center.

```
- (void) incrementAchievementThis:(NSString*)achievementID :(NSInteger) incStep
{
    NSMutableDictionary *achievementDescriptions = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [GKAchievementDescription loadAchievementDescriptionsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *descriptions, NSError *error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Error getting achievement descriptions: %@", error);
        }
        for (GKAchievementDescription *achievementDescription in descriptions) {
            [achievementDescriptions setObject:achievementDescription forKey:achievementDescription.identifier];
        }

    }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got output by below code...

```
- (void) incrementAchievementThis:(NSString*)achievementID :(NSInteger) incStep
{
    [GKAchievement loadAchievementsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *achievements, NSError *error)
     {
         if (error == nil) {
             for (GKAchievement* achievement in achievements) {
                 if ([achievementID isEqualToString:achievement.identifier]) {
                     achievement.percentComplete += incStep;

                     [GKAchievement reportAchievements:@[achievement] withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
                            if (error != nil) {
                                NSLog(@"Error at incrementAchievementThis()");
                            }
                    }];
                 }
             }
         }
         else {
             NSLog(@"Error in loading achievements: %@", error);
         }
     }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Percentages are stored in `GKAchievement percentComplete`, so you need to load (and update and report) `GKAchievement`s instead of `GKAchievementDescription`s.

`GKAchievmenentDescription`s are configured in iTunes Connect and are "read-only" from the point of view of your app.

Comment: and may i know how to load `GKAchievement percentComplete` and how to report back to game center?

Comment: @smitpatel Show some little gratitude and upvote the answer, then I might add some code. (It's all in Apple's documentation, so you can also help yourself.)

Comment: sry mate, i dont have much reputation to up vote you. o/w i surely done.